# get_the_content_feed with paginated posts

Tags: posts, feed, paginate-links

I have a wordpress site and i have been working on it's feed. I noticed that when a post has been paginated with , it only renders the first page of the post. What i need to do is get all the content of the post and not just the first page.

```
while( have_posts()) : the_post();

    ?>
<item>
<title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>

<link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>

<comments><?php comments_link_feed(); ?></comments>

<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>

<dc:creator><![CDATA[<?php the_author(); ?>]]></dc:creator>

<?php
$pub_date= mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false);
```

......

```
$description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; // The Description
$content = get_the_content_feed('rss2');
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about paginated posts which created using `<!--nextpage-->` tag, then you will have to use `the_content_feed` hook to strip that tag and pass the full content. I have tried below code & it does exactly that. But please note it will pass full content to RSS feed for all the posts.

`add_action('the_content_feed', 'strip_nextpage_tag_for_rss');
function strip_nextpage_tag_for_rss() { 
   global $post;
   $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
   $content = str_replace( "\n<!--nextpage-->\n", '', $content );
   $content = str_replace( "\n<!--nextpage-->", '', $content );
   $content = str_replace( "<!--nextpage-->\n", '', $content );
   $content = str_replace( "&lt;!--nextpage--&gt;", '', $content );
   $content = str_replace( "<p>&lt;!&#8211;nextpage&#8211;&gt;</p>", '', $content );
   $content = str_replace( "<p><!--nextpage--></p>", '', $content );
   return $content;
}`

Place above code in your theme's functions.php file. I hope this helps.

Comment: I will test this out as soon as possible and accept your answer. I think this might really work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you face any problem ;-)

Comment: I tried it but i can't seem to figure out how to use it... Could you please tell me? Don't i have to call that function somewhere? Thanks

Comment: I saw your echo $content; but it outputs only the first page... i even tried str_replace but  it doesn't work...

Comment: You just need to place that code in functions.php file of your theme and you need not call the function. Once placed, visit your site /feed URL , ideally you shall see full page content for each post in the feed.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The feed does actually echo out, meaning it uses the added function but it only shows the content before "nextpage" tag. I put your code on the functions.php and i know  the feed is getting affected but the content is still the same

Comment: @Kunal - I think the hook I used before was failing in some scenarios. I have updated my answer with different hook and also updated the code in the function. Please use that code and you should be good. This will definitely crack it. Please let me know how it goes.